# How to make two headers one below other and make them fixed on scrolling?

Tags: html, css, scroll, header, css-position

Here is my HTML code (can't change the order).
I have one div (black) below that one header (yellow) and another div(pink which is another header for me). But the pink one comes at top overlapping with black div.

```
<body>
   <div class="top-block-header" style="background-color:#0e0e0e;color:#fff;padding:7px 0;">
      <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-9" style="font-size:11px;text-transform:uppercase;font-weight:400;line-height:24px;text-align:left;">
               <span style="margin-right: 30px;">Free shipping &amp; Return</span>
               <span style="margin-right: 30px;">money back guarantee</span>
               <span>online support 24/7</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3" style="font-size:11px;text-align:right;font-weight:400;line-height:24px;">
               <span>CALL US <b style="font-weight:600;padding-left:6px;">+ 000 1584 2578</b></span>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="page-wrapper">
      <header class="page-header">
         <div class="header">
            <h1>Logo</h1>
         </div>
      </header>
   </div>
   <div class="header-bottom">
      New header
   </div>
</body>
```

And here is my CSS code

```
* {
    font-family: Helvetica, "Helvetica Neue", "Open Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.4;
    font-size: .9rem;
}

.page-wrapper {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.page-header {
    background-color: #F7D533;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%
}

.header-bottom {
    height: 34px !important;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    z-index: 3;
    background-color: pink;
    position: fixed;
}

body {
    height: 1000px;
}
```

Currently the output is as shown in image below.

[image]

**Without scrolling :**

Black div should be first then followed by yellow header and then pink div.

**On scolling**
I want to let go the black div and only fix the yellow header and pink div.

How to achieve this in only CSS?

Comment: Impossible. CSS cannot detect the scrolling, you need Javascript for that.

Comment: Position fixed won't work?

Comment: You want two fixed divs to clash each other when black one is out?
P.S.
It's irrelevant to the question but i don't recommend you put styles in your html (especially if you already has css file)

Comment: @Nausif I probably misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible using `position:sticky` here is the updated code snippet:

```css
* {
  font-family: Helvetica, "Helvetica Neue", "Open Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.4;
  font-size: .9rem;
  margin: 0;
}

.page-header {
  background-color: #F7D533;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 34px;
}

.header-bottom {
  height: 34px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 3;
  background-color: pink;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 34px;
}

body {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="top-block-header" style="background-color:#0e0e0e;color:#fff;padding:7px 0;">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9" style="font-size:11px;text-transform:uppercase;font-weight:400;line-height:24px;text-align:left;">
          <span style="margin-right: 30px;">Free shipping &amp; Return</span>
          <span style="margin-right: 30px;">money back guarantee</span>
          <span>online support 24/7</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3" style="font-size:11px;text-align:right;font-weight:400;line-height:24px;">
          <span>CALL US <b style="font-weight:600;padding-left:6px;">+ 000 1584 2578</b></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <header class="page-header">
    <div class="header">
      <h1>Logo</h1>
    </div>
  </header>

  <div class="header-bottom">
    New header
  </div>
</body>
```

`position: sticky;` is positioned based on the user's scroll position.

Check here how position sticky works:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_sticky_element.asp

Comment: It worked, thanks!!! you removed "page-wrapper" div , I put it back and replaced css of page-header with page-wrapper. It still works, thanks :).